# Cannot get values from GraphRequest Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm using `Facebook SDK 4.16.1` by using `Profile` I could get `first name`, `last name`, `name` and `id` my code is like this

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

String id, fname, lname, email, name, gender, locale, verified;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.loginactivity);

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
        }
    };

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS));

    FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            FB_TOKEN=loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code
                            response.getError();
                            Log.e("JSON:", object.toString());

                            try {
                                email = object.getString("email");
                                gender = object.getString("gender");
                                locale = object.optString("locale");
                                verified = object.optString("verified");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,first_name,last_name,email,gender,verified,locale");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


            id = profile.getId();
            fname = profile.getFirstName();
            lname = profile.getLastName();
            name = profile.getName();

            nextActivity(profile);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        }
    };

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
}

 }
```

My constants looks like this

```
public static final String[] FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
                                                                "public_profile",
                                                                "user_friends",
                                                                "email" };
```

I'm trying to get the email, gender, locale and if its already verified. How will I get the other information? Mine are always null expect for the items that is get by `Profile`

**Update**

I update my `GraphRequest` like this

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code
                            response.getError();
                            Log.e("JSON-RESULT:", object.toString());

                            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                            try {
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(object.toString());
                                email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                locale = jsonObject.getString("locale");
                                verified = jsonObject.getString("verified");

                                Log.e(TAG, email + " This is the email");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,first_name,last_name,email,gender,verified,locale");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
```

In my `Logcat` it shows that I set the email and the others correctly but it doesn't go inside `GraphRequest` when you put `breakpoints`, and because of this my global `variable` email is still null. Even if in `Log.e("JSON:", object.toString());` and `Log.e(TAG, email + " This is the email");` it shows I get and set the values. I'm wondering how can I get the values of `Bundle`?

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542193/how-to-get-facebook-photo-full-name-gender-using-facebook-sdk-android) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code to fetch other info.....

```
 private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
               // Log.d("Login", "onSuccess");
                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // handle error
                                } else {
                                    email = me.optString("email");
                                    String id = me.optString("id");
                                    String email=me.optString("email");
                                    String name= me.optString("name");
                                    String gender= me.optString("gender");
                                    String verified= me.optBoolean("is_verified") + "";                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel () {
              //  Log.d("Login", "onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError (FacebookException e){
              //  Log.d("Login", "onError " + e);
               }
       };
```

Comment: so I will call `mFacebookCallback`  in my `onCreate` ?

Comment: In the fb sdk 4.1.o onwards you haev to do this in fragments if you have checked the official doc

Comment: register your call back and call it in oncreateview

Comment: I see, i miss that part, I should put it all in a fragment, I will edit it now cause I put it all in my activity.

Comment: No issues you can try it and if any help is required you can ask me.. If it helps you then kindly accept and upvote it so that others can also consider this as correct answer

Comment: does `<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton>` be put in a layout for fragment or activity?

Comment: in fragment add this

Comment: where should I  call this `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());`? I'm a little confuse in the document cause i saw `FragmentActivity` I have a LoginActivity where I will call the fragment and that fragment will do the rest right?

Comment: Add it in activity

Comment: FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getContext()); you can add this in oncreate  of fragment

Comment: Yes :) Thank you!

Comment: I thought I finally get the value, testing it again it seems I get null :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125884/discussion-between-preetika-kaur-and-mori).

Comment: did you check your mail @mori ?

Comment: you put one more question today did you get answer for that as well regarding the internet connectivity

Comment: I haven't get any answer yet :(

Comment: come to discussions

Comment: I replied at discussion